# Setting camera intent to not add in EXIF data

Tags: android

```
        Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     //Using a File so it overwrites previous camera shot
        File pictureFile = new File(cameraImagePath);
        camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));
        startActivityForResult(camera, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

I'm using this code to get a camera shot which is then uploaded to an imageboard. The problem is that on some phones GPS locations are recorded in the EXIF data and users are unknowingly revealing their locations. Is there some value I can add to the intent to tell the camera app not to record any EXIF data?

(Using 1.6 API's also)

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an old question but the answer for anyone else looking, two options spring to mind

1) You could open the image as to a bitmap an save it again, the EXIF information should be lost.

2) You could edit the EXIF data in the jpg using the ExifInterface of the Android SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html